# Данные в Intent для BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcastreceiver

Подскажите уже голову сломал, кладу данные в интент и отправляю широковещательным сообщением, но когда получаю интент, то в нем нет данных.
Отправка:

```html
 if (Activity_chat.isOpen &&
                        (Activity_chat.chat_ID.equals(jsonObject.getString("visitor_id")))) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
                    Log.e("MyFirebaseMsgService1", jsonObject.getString("message"));
                    intent.putExtra("chat_message", jsonObject.getString("message"));
                    sendBroadcast(intent);

                    Log.e("MyFirebaseMsgService1", "broadcastsending");
                }
```

тут в логах все данные есть.
Потом получаю этот интент в Активити:

```html
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           // String chatReceve=getIntent().getStringExtra("chat_message");
            if (intent.getAction().equals(BROADCAST_ACTION)) {
                Log.d("MyFirebaseMsgService2", "null22");
                if (getIntent().getExtras().getString("chat_message") == null) {
                    Log.d("MyFirebaseMsgService2", "null");}
                else{
                    String chatReceve=getIntent().getExtras().getString("chat_message");
                    Log.d("MyFirebaseMsgService2", getIntent().getExtras().getString("chat_message"));
   

            }
            }
```

И получаю что данных в ключе chat_message нет. В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getIntent()` - это метод активности и он возвращает её интент.
Вместо этого используйте пришедший в `onReceive` параметр `intent`:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(BROADCAST_ACTION)) {
        Log.d("MyFirebaseMsgService2", "null22");
        String chatReceve = intent.getExtras().getString("chat_message");
        if (chatReceve == null) {
            Log.d("MyFirebaseMsgService2", "null");
        } else {
            Log.d("MyFirebaseMsgService2", chatReceve);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо помогло.Понял свою ошибку.